# Shared Memory: shmat() call is successful but does not increment nattach

Tags: c, shared-memory

I'm trying to attach an existing shared memory segment, but the nattach value does not increment, as indicated in the api for `shmat`.

My code:

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/errno.h>

void attachSharedMem(char* shm_id) {
    printf("Attach shared mem ID %s ", shm_id);
    void* res;
    res = shmat(atoi(shm_id), NULL, 0);
    printf("\nAttach result %p", res);
    printf("\nError %d", errno);
}
```

The results:

```
Attach shared mem ID 112590871 
Attach result 0x7f63df61e000
Error 0
```

But running `ipcs -m` shows `nattach` is still 0 for shmid 112590871

If I pass a bogus shmid it returns -1 and sets errno to 22, so it seems the call with the valid shmid is successful. Successive calls return a different address, so I think I'm attaching the segment to multiple locations, but nattach never increments.

Comment: Did you run `ipcs -m` while the process, which attached the shm segment, was still running?

Comment: I ran `ipcs -m` after the process which attached had exited, but while the process which created the shared memory segment was still running. Specifically, the eclipse launcher creates the segment, with nattach = 0. While eclipse is still running, I run the C code to attach the segment. I'm trying to work around this eclipse bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=492618

Comment: Then it works as expected: nattach is the number of processes with have the shm segment attached _at the moment_, this does not count past attaches, which were detached (either explicitly with shmdt or implicitly by terminating the process).

Comment: Yes of course, I should have realized that. I'm testing my C code separately now, so it exits. I put a 30-second sleep in before exiting, and natttach is incremented. I'm going to invoke the C function via JNI from an eclipse RCP plug-in, in which case the nattach count will persist as needed until the eclipse app exits.